# Is it possible to have a shared folder as "origin" and have it's content automatically synced with a specific branch

Tags: git

We have an application that calls some Stored Procedures from a network shared folder where we (as of now) edit directly those procedures (backing them up manually). I'd like to have them versioned so we can rollback to previous version and be more organized.

What i had in mind was to use the folder where the application reads the procedure as "origin" for my local repository. After i make the changes in my working copy on my local environment i commit and push to the remote and the folder automatically pulls and modify it's content to reflect the changes.

Is it possible to do so with GIT?
We are multiple people working on those procedures so we can't use the network shared folder as working copy and have the actual remote on another system (the enterprise git server for example)

Edit:

Example:

> Let's say the application reads the procedures from the shared folder
>   on server A. On our local machines (B and C) i wan't to have a local
>   repo that has the shared folder as remote origin so that we can commit
>   and push our changes to A. After we push our changes, A should "pull
>   from itself" (if that makes any sense) to have it's folder reflect tha
>   changes in the pushed commits. So that the application reading from
>   the folder on A is using the latest version of the procedures.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [git hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) to execute some steps after you push to your repository, for example, update your procedures (by pulling from the repo).

Comment: But where is the hook placed? In my local reposotory? And how is the remote repository created? It can't be a bare repository

Comment: Let's say the application reads the procedures from the shared folder on server A. On our local machines (B and C) i wan't to have a local repo that has the shared folder as remote origin so that we can commit and push our changes to A. After we push our changes, A should "pull from itself" (if that makes any sense) to have it's folder reflect tha changes in the pushed commits. So that the application reading from the folder on A is using the latest version of the procedures.

Comment: Then you could put a hook in the repo on server A, and it should update it's working copy after every push. You can use [file protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) to communicate with the repo. Does it make sense?